# GeckoWebBrowser crash in anyCPU

Tags: c#, geckofx

In a C# .Net 4.7.2 WPF project, I'm loading the GeckoWebBrowser component from a UserControl. I'm using the nuget package id="Geckofx60.64" version="60.0.18" .

My solution and project are configured with "Any CPU" in VS2017.

In order to get the Firefox64 repository, I add the nuget package id="Geckofx60.64.Windows" version="0.7.0".

Everything is OK, then I'm calling an "index.html" page with the following code

```
public partial class Simulator : UserControl
{
    readonly string indexPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Templates", "index.html");

    private GeckoWebBrowser _browser;

    public Simulator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox64");

        var host = new WindowsFormsHost();
        _browser = new GeckoWebBrowser();

        host.Child = _browser;
        GridWeb.Children.Add(host);
    }

    private void Datacontext_ConfigurationChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            _browser.Navigate(indexPath)
        );
    }

    private void Simulator_OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var datacontext = DataContext as ServicesViewModel;
        if (datacontext != null)
        {
            datacontext.ConfigurationChanged -= Datacontext_ConfigurationChanged;
            datacontext.ConfigurationChanged += Datacontext_ConfigurationChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

The logic in my application is to refresh the browser each time I have some changes in my local objects.

`Datacontext_ConfigurationChanged` will be called for each change.

It's working pretty well except that I can receive this exception randomly during a refresh

```
"System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory.."
```

This exception crashes my app, and I can't find any solution for this exception.
Thank you for your help !

Comment: I see you're using x64 geckofx binaries, but using AnyCPU. Have you turned off "Prefer 32-bit" in the build settings? Its on by default. If you haven't, its trying to run as 32 bit instead of 64 bit.

Comment: Hi, thank you, but "Prefer 32-bit" is not checked (for all projects) in build settings.

Comment: System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)

Answer (score 2):

I changed to Geckofx45.64 and now it's ok..